# How can I use the Broadleaf REST API?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm trying to use the REST APIs built into Broadleaf eCommerce. The instructions on their site say to add a reference to `/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rest-api.xml` in `web.xml`, but `/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rest-api.xml` doesn't exist.  It was [renamed on January 14, 2015](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/commit/f861282185cdcad12a046f6f049bf1744e217c72#diff-c8f6febde1c468f4852480d875e968d7) by @phillipuniverse. The current `web.xml` from the DemoSite [has a reference](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/blob/master/site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L25) to the new filename (`applicationContext-rest-api-security.xml`). So, it seems like nothing needs to be done to enable REST -- they are enabled by default.

However, when I try to access them, I get:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'null' not supported

I really am sending a Content-Type header. This appears to be an incorrect exception based on a [known bug in Jackson](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/77132-json-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception). It has something to do with types not being serializable.

I think that means the wrapper classes need to be fixed. They are what gets serialized. (right?) I'm trying to figure out if this is because I'm doing something wrong, or if it's a bug in BroadleafCommerce.

Also, I'm kinda new with Maven, so I'm not sure how to go about trying to fix this. The DemoSite pulls BroadLeafCommerce from a repo. How do I tell it to look at my local git clone of BroadleafCommerce? (I realize this is a different question, but it's related because it's the only way I can think of fixing the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to fix your problem:

1. Set a `Content-Type` HTTP header to either `application/json` (the default) or `application/xml`
2. Remove all the `consumes` from all the endpoints except for ones that have an `@RequestBody`

For instance, if you have an endpoint annotated with:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/cart",
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public class CartEndpoint extends org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.api.endpoint.order.CartEndpoint`

You can replace that with:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/cart",
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public class CartEndpoint extends org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.api.endpoint.order.CartEndpoint`

Comment: I am setting the Content-Type header. The error message is misleading. See the link I included above about a bug in Jackson.

Comment: Did you try removing all of the consumes attributes on @RequestMapping? I'm pretty sure that it doesn't have to do with a Jackson parsing bug. Which endpoint are you trying to hit specifically? Is it one that you actually expect deserialization to occur?

Comment: I removed the `consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}` and it worked.

Comment: Cool. Just for others reading, the `consumes` attribute on the annotation is the cause of requiring a Content-Type header. If that attribute is removed, then you no longer need to send a Content-Type header in the request. Since removing `consumes` from the endpoints fixed your issue, that means that somehow you weren't actually sending the `Content-Type` HTTP header; maybe there was a typo or there's a different way to do that in the library that you're using (it's different than a request attribute or a POST value).